# Add a List to my layout

Tags: android

I want to create a layout like this:

On the top a TextView, after it a scrollable list of words, in the bottom two buttons.

But in order to create a scrollable list I think I must use ListActivity, but I want to create an Activity so the only scrollable part is the list and the TextView and buttons are fixed.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use ListActivity and use a RelativeLayout (or Linearlayou I think?) with the TextView, ListView, etc. Then only ListView will scroll.

Comment: But cant I use Activity and make list scrollable aswell?

Comment: Maybe, but I don't see any good reason for not using ListActivity. Since it only makes the list scrollable and isn't it that you want?